# I have to make it in a Row but my result is something else

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, frontend

The result that I don't want:

[image: Result which I don`t want]

The result which I want:

[image: Result which I want]
**Using Bootstrap 4.4.1**
also, use grids but no change occurs

```html
<body>
  <div style="margin-left: 72%;">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="font-weight-bold textleft">Print Date: </th>
          <td><span class="font-weight-light"> @DateTime.Now</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="font-weight-bold textleft">Print at: </th>
          <td><span class="font-weight-light textleft"> @getLoginProp.BranchName</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="font-weight-bold textleft">Print by: </th>
          <td><span class="font-weight-light textleft"> @getLoginProp.UserName</span></td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>

  <h3>@Model.BranchName</h3>
  <h2>Purchase Receive</h2>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are misusing the HTML `<table>` element. I suggest you apply styling rules to keep the two sections, with some CSS if necessary.

Keep it semantic! Imagine a blind user being told they are looking at a table, when in fact the information within isn't mean to be read in a tabular way.

There are several ways, but I would suggest reading [this](https://medium.com/@ManBearPigCode/two-coding-techniques-to-quickly-build-a-horizontal-section-webpage-b48dfe44c70e) and [this](https://www.w3.org/html/wiki/Elements/aside#:%7E:text=The%20element%20represents%20a,considered%20separate%20from%20that%20content.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution

```
  <body>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
      <div>
        <h3>@Model.BranchName</h3>
        <h2>Purchase Receive</h2>
      </div>
      <div>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="font-weight-bold textleft">Print Date:</th>
              <td>
                <span class="font-weight-light"> @DateTime.Now </span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class="font-weight-bold textleft">Print at:</th>
              <td>
                <span class="font-weight-light textleft">
                  @getLoginProp.BranchName
                </span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class="font-weight-bold textleft">Print by:</th>
              <td>
                <span class="font-weight-light textleft">
                  @getLoginProp.UserName
                </span>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```